# Ternary operator not behaving as intended

Tags: node.js, ternary-operator

**[my Code link](https://ide.codingblocks.com/s/45945)**

on line `currentEnvironment = typeof (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'string') ? currentEnvironment.toLowerCase() : '';`

when I pass the input   `uptime-monitoring-app >> NODE_ENV=production node app.js`  it works without any issue.

```
Command Line arguments :
0: /usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.15.0/bin/node
1: /Users/tentacion/Documents/CODE/Node without NPM/uptime-monitoring-app/app.js
string

Server Started @ 5000           Environment : production
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

BUT for the input   `uptime-monitoring-app >> Nnode app.js`   it throws error, because now the NODE_ENV variable is undefined now.

```
Command Line arguments :
0: /usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.15.0/bin/node
1: /Users/tentacion/Documents/CODE/Node without NPM/uptime-monitoring-app/app.js
undefined
/Users/tentacion/Documents/CODE/Node without NPM/uptime-monitoring-app/envConfig.js:66
currentEnvironment = typeof (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'string') ? currentEnvironment.toLowerCase() : '';
                                                                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tentacion/Documents/CODE/Node without NPM/uptime-monitoring-app/envConfig.js:66:86)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tentacion/Documents/CODE/Node without NPM/uptime-monitoring-app/app.js:11:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
  uptime-monitoring-app >>
```

What I expected
if the `NODE_ENV` variable is undefined then the expression   `typeof (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'string')`   would be false so the next statement should be executed. ie assigning it with the empty string.

Please help, I don't know what am I doing wrong. I am new to node

Comment: `typeof (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'string') ?` will evaluate to something like `typeof (true) ?` or `typeof (false) ?`, which will evaluate to `'boolean' ?`, which is truthy. Remove your parentheses

Comment: I am such a stupid dumb ass.. **thanks bro**

Answer (score 1):

`process.env.XXX` are always either a string or undefined.

Prefer something like `const { XXX = 'some-default-value' } = process.env`, which is called object destructuring, which will either use the provided value for XXX or give it a default value if it is undefined.

Comment: Why upvote then remove the upvote? What's wrong with my answer?